# How to populate a 2d array with items based on conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

A bit of background

I'm working on a mini project to build a 32 x 32 array of arrays with various numbers, that represent tiles for small map. These tiles will be represented then visually to create what is seemingly a random map generator and I am doing this solely in JS as a means to reinforce what I already understand about arrays.

For additional context: I want to have some default values like a 3 x 3 row throughout the array that stays the same (blank / walkable) to guarantee a walkable area of the map.

The Problem

I have currently gotten it to populate the arrays based on a default value:

```js
function createAndFillTwoDArray({
  rows,
  columns,
  defaultValue
}) {
  return Array.from({
      length: rows
    }, () =>
    Array.from({
      length: columns
    }, () => defaultValue)
  );
}

const values = createAndFillTwoDArray({
  rows: 32,
  columns: 32,
  defaultValue: "✔️",
});

// This populates the array into HTML, and should not effect the actual generation
const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  const fields = values[i];

  for (let j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
    const field = fields[j];
    const td = document.createElement("td");

    td.textContent = field;

    tr.appendChild(td);
  }

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

and from there is our problem, I am trying to figure out how I can pass in a function or an object that will allow me to populate each array but cannot reference the array from outside the scope of the createAndFillTwoDArray func

I've tried a few methods, firstly I tried removing the default value from the arrow function and adding an if else looping statement into that, followed by trying to make default value an object.

Both of these did not work and from there I went to try creating it inside the function and outside of the array creation, this also did not work and led to my live-server crashing, which was not expected.

```js
function createAndFillTwoDArray({
  rows,
  columns
}) {
  const arr = Array.from({
      length: rows
    }, () =>
    Array.from({
      length: columns
    }, () => {})
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr.push("✔️");
  }
  return arr;
}

const values = createAndFillTwoDArray({
  rows: 32,
  columns: 32,
});
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to accomplish that is causing the problem especially with the code that you have tried. Are you saying that you want to control which elements get the default value vs all of the elements in your original function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the default value to be a function rather than a single value, just call it in the creation function.

Since `Array.from()` passes the index to the populate function, I'm passing that along to the creation function.

```js
function createAndFillTwoDArray({
  rows,
  columns,
  defaultFunc
}) {
  return Array.from({
      length: rows
    }, (_, row) =>
    Array.from({
      length: columns
    }, (_, col) => defaultFunc(row, col))
  );
}

const values = createAndFillTwoDArray({
  rows: 32,
  columns: 32,
  defaultFunc: (x, y) => x == y ? "" : "✔️",
});

// This populates the array into HTML, and should not effect the actual generation
const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  const fields = values[i];

  for (let j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
    const field = fields[j];
    const td = document.createElement("td");

    td.textContent = field;

    tr.appendChild(td);
  }

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```